# I cannot update an Access 2007 table using C# statements

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, ado.net, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to add records to a MS Access table 2007 using a C# application. My table consists of 3 fields: `ID`, `Name` and `phone`.

For example I tried to add a record for some one with these data: `ID=1`, `Name=Boulis`, and `phone=1212422`. The query didn't return any errors but I didn't find this data in my table.

But the most surprising matter is that when I tried to add the same previous data I got an error saying:

> "The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship.  Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again."

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();

    string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\boulis.accdb;;Persist Security Info=False ";

    con.ConnectionString = ConnStr;
    con .Open();
    MessageBox.Show("The connection is available now");
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO info(ID, Name, phone) Values(@StudIDTxt, @StudNameTxt, @StudCNCITxt)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudIDTxt",1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudNameTxt", "boulis");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudCNCITxt", 1212422);

    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("table is already updated");
}
```

Comment: And where is this code you speak of? Please post it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you receive on the second attempt clearly indicates that the first attempt was successful. If you already had the table open in Access before performing the INSERT in C# then you won't be able to see the new record until you either

- close and re-open the table in Access, or
- refresh the Datasheet View (or Form, or whatever). That can be accomplished by clicking the "Refresh All" button in the "Records" section of the "Home" tab (in Access 2010, anyway).

Comment: I have already refreshed and re_opened the database but no change.